# Send JSON data using VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I am trying to send JSON data to a web service using VB.NET.  I am using the System.Web.Script.Serialization library but it is not working.  When I look at the web service, it is just displaying: {METHOD = getMACAddress}

```
 Private Function sendWebRequest()
    Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.1/scripts/service.php"), HttpWebRequest)

    ' Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.KeepAlive = True
    Dim Data As String =  "{METHOD = getMACAddress}"
    Dim postData As String = json.Serialize(Data)
    MsgBox(Data, 0, "Info")
    Dim byteData As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    ' Get the request stream.
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    ' Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    ' Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close()

    ' Get the response.
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    ' Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
    ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    ' Read the content.
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    ' Display the content.
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
    ' Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()
End Function
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to send?  Did you step through the code to see what `postData` looks like?

Comment: So I am using VB to connect to a web service that has this code                      if ($_SERVER['HTTP_METHOD'] === 'getMACAddress'){
    if($_POST == null){
       $handle  = fopen('php://input', 'r');
        $rawData = fgets($handle);
        $body = json_decode($rawData);

Comment: use ajax to send the data from vb to a php page.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I believe what you are looking for are webmethods.

EG: Default.aspx.vb

```
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse:=False)> _
Public Function AddInt(A as Integer, B as Integer) As Integer
    return A + B
End Function
```

Then from your client use ensure that your post your parameters to the method using contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetAddInt() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/AddInt",
        data: '{A: 5, B: 7}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) { alert(response.d); },
        failure: function(response) { alert('Error'); }
    });
}
</script>
```

Although this is a simplistic example, you can expand this by returning structured data or objects.  Serialization is handled for you.

Note: Its very important that you set the content type or .NET will return the data in XML.

Comment: I am actually trying to send data to a web service from VB.  The code I am connecting to looks like this:                                             if ($_SERVER['HTTP_METHOD'] === 'getMACAddress'){
    if($_POST == null){
       $handle  = fopen('php://input', 'r');
        $rawData = fgets($handle);
        $body = json_decode($rawData);